# Bar width issue on achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a problem with my chart using achartengine. I set data for dataset from my sqlite db, I can show it successfully on the chart but the bar width is to narrow. Here are my `GenerateEngine` class to generate bar from sqlite db.

```
public class GenerateChart {

private ExpensesDataSource datasource;
private SpinnerValues spinnerValues = new SpinnerValues();

private SimpleDateFormat monthFormat, yearFormat;
String month, year;
List<String> values;
XYSeries series;

public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getExpensesBarDataset(Context context) {

    datasource = new ExpensesDataSource(context);

    monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    month = monthFormat.format(new Date());

    yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    year = yearFormat.format(new Date());

    datasource.openToRead();
    values = datasource.GetTotalEachCategory(month, year);
    datasource.close();

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYSeries series;
    for(int i = 0; i < spinnerValues.categoryText.length; i++) {
       series = new XYSeries(spinnerValues.categoryText[i]);
       series.add(i, Double.parseDouble(values.get(i)));

       dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
    return dataset;
}

public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getExpensesBarRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 40, 15, 0 });

    XYSeriesRenderer r;

    for(int i = 0; i < spinnerValues.categoryColor.length; i++) {
        r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.parseColor(spinnerValues.categoryColor[i]));
        r.setLineWidth(20);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        r.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
}

public void myChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String month, String year) {
    renderer.setChartTitle("Pratinjau Grafik Pengeluaran Bulan " + month + " Tahun " + year);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(-10);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(10);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(500000);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(.1);
    renderer.setXTitle("Kategori");
    renderer.setYTitle("Total Pengeluaran");
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setXLabels(0); // sets the number of integer labels to appear
}}
```

Here is what I got from my class.[image]

I want to add the width of the bar so it will proper. I will appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: try renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);

Comment: I've tried it before, but it didn't take any changes.

Comment: and how about renderer.setBarWidth()??

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I try to use that method in my class, but i can't find the method. Am I missing something to use that method?

Comment: look at this apis http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**setBarWidth** api is used for **XYMultipleSeriesRenderer**
Refer this Api -->[API](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html)

So in ur code u need to change this :

```
Inside getExpensesBarRenderer() Api
renderer.setBarWidth()
```

Comment: The android studio return an error "Can not resolve method setBarWidth()", but I am able to add the width by changing `setBarSpacing(-0.9)` as suggested by this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809477/bar-graph-using-achartengine

Comment: can u plz tell me which version of achartengine jar u using?

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is clear. Now I am able to use `setBarWidth();`

Comment: Yes. I didn't realize that I used the old version.